# Qual é a palavra mais educada? Seio, peito, mama ou outra?

Tags: vocabulário

Eu entendo que todas estas palavras possam ser sinónimas, mas qual é a palavra mais educada ou adequada, e menos grosseira (calão) a usar quando se referem a esta parte do corpo feminino?

Answer (score 10):

Para muitas pessoas, e de acordo com o dicionário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa, as três palavras são igualmente aceitáveis. Por exemplo, o termo oficial é *cancro da mama* e não *cancro do seio/peito*. Contudo, creio que algumas pessoas poderão ter reticências em relação a *mama*. Eu não diria, *A Sr.ª tem um moscardo na mama; cuidado que ainda a pica* a um mulher com quem não tivesse confiança; usaria *peito*. *Seio* é a mais formal de todas as três palavras.

*Teta* aplica-se a animais fêmeas. Aplicado a mulheres é rude.

*Peito* e seio poderão ser mais ambíguos que *mama*, pois podem também indicar toda a área entre a barriga e os ombros.

Uma mulher tem duas *mamas*, mas *peito* e *seio*, no singular, podem designar apenas uma mama ou as duas.

Depois de matutar sobre este assunto, ocorreram-me mais umas ideias que poderão ser relevantes. Quando falamos com uma mulher ou uma adolescente, ou falamos duma mulher ou adolescente, queremos normalmente evitar mostrar interesse sexual, que poderia ser ofensivo. Ora das palavras *mama*, *peito* e *seio*, pelo menos em Portugal, *mama* é a que mais facilmente ganha conotação sexual. É a palavra tipicamente usada por grupos de rapazes ou homens amigos em discussões privadas sobre os atrativos físicos duma mulher; isto se não usarem *teta*. Talvez isto se deva a *mama* designar especificamente cada uma das partes protuberantes do peito duma mulher, enquanto *peito* e *seio* podem designar também toda a área envolvente.

Por isso, quando haja a possibilidade de melindrar, é mais seguro usar *peito* ou *seio* do que *mama*. Não por a palavra ser imprópria, mas por uma razão semelhante à que me permitiria tocar numa mulher para enxotar um moscardo, se o moscardo estivesse pousado no braço, mas não se estivesse pousado numa mama. Neste último caso avisá-la-ia.

Está de acordo com esta ideia o facto de *maminha* ser a palavra usada em Portugal para falarmos da mama duma menina (ou menino) obviamente pré-púbere. Crianças são tidas por seres assexuais.

Em discussões técnicas ou de tal natureza que não possa transparecer qualquer intenção sexual, *mama* é aceitável. Já agora seria interessante ouvir a opinião de mulheres sobre isto.

Comment: No Brasil, evite usar *pica* e *mama* na mesma frase ;)

Comment: Mesmo para advertir da eminência de ser picada por um moscardo? Ou vespa, ou abelha? Imagino que usar o verbo _ferrar_ em vez de _picar_ não melhore muito as coisas?

Comment: Basta conjugar o verbo de outra forma, ex: "cuidado pra ela não te picar" ou "cuidado pra não ser picada". Apenas "pica", em si, que cria um duplo sentido (gíria para "pênis"). A propósito, "ferrar" também pode ser uma gíria com conotação sexual (o que não é? rsrs), mas nesse contexto não há mal em usá-la no lugar de "picar" ("cuidado que ainda a ferra"). Embora no Brasil usemos ["ferroar"](http://www.dicio.com.br/ferroar/) em vez de "ferrar".

Comment: No Brasil, quem teve uma educação mais diferenciada aceita a palavra mama como o termo correto.  Eu, por ser médico, não uso outra palavra que não seja mama, a não ser quando estou querendo dar uma conotação erótica ou sexual.

Comment: Curioso. Em Portugal, _mama_ é a palavra que mais facilmente ganha conotação sexual, na linguagem informal. _Seio_ também pode ser usado num contexto erótico, mas é mais literário. Em linguagem popular, uma mulher com peito avantajado diz-se _mamalhuda._

Comment: Precisamente, @mgibsonbr, eu pensei que não devesse usar _pica_ por _picar_ ter conotação sexual, a mesma que _ferrar/ferroar._

Answer (score 10):

- **Mama** - Em medicina e outras ciências da saúde usa-se o termo "mama".  Não se diz câncer (cancro) de seio, e muito menos "seiografia".  Tudo o que se refere às glândulas mamáreas, femininas ou masculinas (sim, homens também as têm e câncer de glãndulas mamáreas também ocorre em homens), usa a palavra "mama". "Ela pretende fazer uma cirurgia de redução de mamas."
- **Peito** é uma palavra que designa a parte anterior do tórax, incluindo as glândulas mamáreas. Não é um termo chulo.  "O jogador aparou a bola no peito e chutou direto a gol"  "Sinto uma dor no peito"  "É meu amigo do peito."  Contudo, também pode se referir às mamas como em "meu bebê ainda está mamando no peito".
- **Seio** - Aqui cabem dois significados: em medicina, seio é o espaço entre as duas mamas. Como os brasileiros em geral evitam a palavra "mama" (acham feio, não sei) chamam as mamas de seios.
- **Tetas** - É uma palavra que se usa quando nos referimos às glândulas mamáreas de animais (fêmeas). Também pode-se usar para mulheres mas é extremamente vulgar.
- **Busto** - Busto refere-se a todo o tórax e cabeça.  No entanto, quando querem se referir a tamanho das mamas de uma forma polida, algumas pessoas dizem "ela tem muito busto, ou pouco busto. Também é muito usado quando se fala em medidas: "ela tem 98 centímetros de busto".

**Qual palavra usar?** -  Depende de com quem você fala e do assunto.

Eu uso "mamas" quando me refiro a qualquer aspecto científico.  Uso peitinho, peitões, quando não há mulheres presentes e o contexto é erótico. Você também pode usá-los quando estiver em momento íntimo com seu/sua parceiro. Pode-se usar "seio" ou "seios" de forma genérica para se referir às mamas, e muita gente o faz.

Comment: Curioso: em Portugal, "vulgar" é "comum" e "ordinário" é "insolente" ou "mal-educado".

Comment: @ANeves No Brasil também, ao menos segundo a norma culta (ex.: latim clássico vs. latim vulgar), a diferença está mais nos padrões de uso. Quase ninguém utiliza "vulgar" com o sentido de "comum", e a palavra tem uma conotação negativa (tipo, como o oposto de "fino", "refinado", "sofisticado"). Já "ordinário" também tem esse sentido quando aplicado a um indivíduo, mas quanto aplicado a uma *situação* ela toma o sentido original, de "comum". P.S. Dê uma olhada na [etimologia](https://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/ordin%C3%A1rio#Etimologia) da palavra "ordinário", eu achei bem esclarecedora.

Comment: Não sei se repararam mas "comum" também é o oposto de "fino, refinado e sofisticado".

Comment: @JorgeB. De fato! O que quis dizer é que algo comum/vulgar/ordinário não é *necessariamente* uma coisa ruim, nem algo fino/refinado/sofisticado/extraordinário uma coisa boa. Mas tanto "vulgar" quanto "ordinário" são frequentemente usados pejorativamente, e muito embora a **origem** desse uso seja alguém importante "olhando de cima" alguém desimportante, nem sempre isso se reflete no uso contemporâneo desses termos. No Brasil, "vulgar" é sempre pejorativo, e "ordinário" só é pejorativo quando aplicado a um indivíduo. Já "comum" é normalmente usado com um tom mais neutro.

Comment: Eu disse lá em cima que geralmente se diz "mama" ao falar com mulheres que estão amamentando, mas há poucas horas nossa pediatra me contradisse: perguntou à minha esposa se nosso filho já tinha parado de mamar no "peito". Mas ela usava "mama" ao se referir a um seio específico, quando dizia para alternar o bebê de um para o outro.

Comment: @bfavaretto "mamar no peito" é idiomático.  Principalmente porque "mamar na mama" soa como um pleonasmo.

Answer (score 8):

Todos os três termos podem ser usados sem parecer rude (desde é claro que o restante da frase não tenha essa natureza). Entretanto, há pequenas diferenças entre eles:

- [*Mama*](https://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/mama) refere-se de forma inambígua (quando usado como substantivo) àquela parte da anatomia, e talvez por essa razão seja o termo mais utilizado em um contexo médico. No Brasil, é raramente usado numa conversa coloquial, pois é visto como muito formal.
- [*Peito*](https://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/peito) pode se referir à mama ou ao tórax de um modo geral (quando usado nesse sentido, é mais comum se referir à parte da frente da caixa toráxica, e à parte de trás como "costas"). Essa ambiguidade pode ser usada propositalmente para evitar uma referência direta à mama, caso o falante se sinta desconfortável em fazê-lo.
- [*Seio*](https://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/seio) em seu uso corrente também se refere à mama, embora em sua origem (do latim *sinus* - "espaço oco") essa palavra era usada para descrever o vão entre as mamas. No Brasil, seu uso é mais coloquial, sendo particularmente usado quando se busca um contexto sensual, porém não chulo (por exemplo, quando se quer fazer um elogio, mas somente se os interlocutores têm intimidade suficiente entre si).

Como [apontado por Jacinto](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/811/74), há também um quarto termo, ["teta"](https://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/teta), mas que em geral é sempre considerado chulo/rude, pois é mais usado ao se referir a animais. Também é bom observar que o uso apropriado varia de região para região (presumo que "seio" seja mais formal em Portugal como um todo, mas mesmo aqui no Brasil as minhas observações acima não são necessariamente aplicáveis a todas as suas regiões), embora costuma-se levar em consideração a origem do falante num contexto mais amplo (i.e. se pelo seu sotaque está claro que você vem de outra região ou mesmo de outro país, o uso da palavra "errada" não soará automaticamente rude).

Answer (score 6):

Apesar do [Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/seio) apontar os 3 termos como sinônimos, como falante nativo do Português Brasileiro posso dizer que *mama* parece ser um termo mais médico (*mamografia*, ou *câncer de mama* p.ex.).

*Peito*, pelo menos no Brasil, é um termo mais chulo, principalmente em suas variações *peituda* e *peitão*, por exemplo.

*Seio* parece ser a palavra mais adequada a ser usada em uma conversa coloquial.

Comment: Não necessariamente chula, só mais informal. "Peituda" sim é chula, mas não "peito".

Comment: Detalhe: se estiver falando com/sobre uma mulher que está amamentando, é natural usar *mama*, mais que *seio*.